# Drupal drop down menu shows child items only when parent is selected

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I am new to Drupal. I am trying to make a website where the menu has child items. eg when I click on "Places" it should drop down a menu with child items like "INDIA","USA","CHINA" etc. For that I added a content(basic page) Places with menu link name "Places". Again added content "INDIA",menu linnk title "INDIA" with parent menu selected as "Places". If I am currently selecting "Places" it works preefectly fine. But if I am in Home or other menu item, selecting "Places" does not appear the drop down. I tried it in two/three themes( all free) , same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using superfish menu. Since you are new to Drupal, I would advise you to search first on Drupal.org website for modules.